# Woocommerce Datepicker Always On

Tags: php, jquery, css, woocommerce, datepicker

Please note that i have added a custom field in my checkout form using plugin "Flexible Woocommerce Checkout Field Editor". Now i am trying to have the datepicker show always on the page. For that i have used tried the following:

```
#ui-datepicker-div
{display: block;}
```

Or

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function(){
                jQuery("#ui-datepicker-div").show();
});
```

However nothing seems to work. Really appreciate your help. You can check the website at twomoms.kitchen

Appreciate your help.

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>` add that before closing `<head>` tag. Jquery is only called after function trying to run, on `windows load`. Think it should help.

Comment: Addign the script is making the page blank. Not sure why? Do you have any idea?

Comment: could be because previous versions is in your footer, try adding the Jquery as the below answer, so that the function runs when the document is loaded, which should do because then the jquery is already loaded , and then no need to add it again as my comment above.

Comment: tried . Does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try help, so in your console you wil see that `Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined at (index):137` which means that JQuery is not identified.

**jquery** not the same as **jQuery**

Replace this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

 jQuery(function () {
 jQuery(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
 sticky_relocate();

 jQuery(this).scrollTop();
 });

 function sticky_relocate() { 
 if ( jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
 jQuery('#sticky').addClass('stick');
 } else {
 jQuery('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
 }
 }

    jQuery(function() {
         jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
             altField: '#wc_order_field_2563', //setting alternate field
             altFormat: 'dd-MM-yy', //setting alternate date format
             fielddateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' //this is the date format for datepicker field
         });
    });

</script>
```

Then for the *datepicker* :

```js
    jQuery(function() {
         jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
             altField: '#wc_order_field_2563', //setting alternate field
             altFormat: 'dd-MM-yy', //setting alternate date format
             fielddateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' //this is the date format for datepicker field
         });
    });
```

```css
input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="tel"], input[type="password"], input[type="search"], textarea {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 2;
    padding-left: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    width: 100%;
}

.woocommerce-billing-fields label, .woocommerce-shipping-fields label, .woocommerce-account-fields label, .woocommerce-additional-fields__field-wrapper label {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <ul>
 <li>i took your HTML from the site, twomoms.kitchen, dont need to make modification to it</li>
 <li>just add this new #datepicker div on top of the html as below</li>
 <li>in the jQuery function the input fields id gets called as can see below</li>
 <li>You can add this Jquery in the <em>script</em> tag in your header ,should work</li>
 <li><strong>goodluck</strong>, comment if you need me</li>
 </ul>


<!-- ADD this div -->
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<!-- ADD this div -->

<div class="woocommerce-additional-fields__field-wrapper">
<p class="form-row form-row-first validate-required" id="wc_order_field_2563_field" data-priority="">
<label for="wc_order_field_2563" class="">Pickup Date <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>
</label>
<input type="text" class="input-text  hasDatepicker" name="wc_order_field_2563" id="wc_order_field_2563" placeholder="Click here to choose your pickup date*: (Tuesday - Saturday)" value="">
</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ylama, thank once again. But when i make these changes, the page goes blank :(. Not sure why. Should i add the jquery before all of this code ?

Comment: clear your cache, maybe just a Ctrl + F5 should do. also please just replace the script ` jquery(function () {` with the document ready i added.

Comment: Have done multiple Ctrl+F5 but the page just stays blank. Thank you for all the help but this isn't working. Need help

Comment: I removed the piece of code there and put the #ui-datepicker-div with jquery instead of documnet. ready. The page loaded however nothing happened on the page. Any pointers for that please?

Comment: The update again makes the page blank. you can see it now.

Comment: There was one $ that i replaced with jQuery. However the calendar is not displayed.

Comment: ill have a look atleast you have no more js errors.

Comment: Thank you for that. Appreciate it Yes please have a look at the main question. Will be waiting for your response.

Comment: your date picker works click in the box where it says "Choose your pickup date*:"

Comment: Yes it does. I have already taken care of it before asking this question. The actual question was to have it "Visible" Always and not on the click in the textbox only.

Comment: updated it in answer above @maddysanoo , first initilize the date picker, then on document ready using **jQuery** show it. Also added JSfiddle to answer

Comment: @maddysanoo the new update should work as shown in the FSFiddle, also i see the basic `jquery` errors are back on that page, its important to have it as `jQuery` else it would always show the error and not work.

Comment: Let me apply that and update you here. It is back because my client was not able to see the website with the changes i have made. Moreover, @Ylama can you please conifrm if the above change will put the elements below it to right at the end? As it has to be this way. Lastly, the calendar is disappearing when we select a date. It should stay there please.

Comment: @maddysanoo to always make it vissible add the datepicket to an `div` tag and not input tag.

Comment: I did please check the fiddle. However how can i put the selected value from calender shown in the text box. Can you please let me know. https://jsfiddle.net/ylama/wkdc0b7f/2/

Comment: Updated my anwser hope it helps, it really should.

Comment: Apologies for the trouble but jsfiddle does not seem to be updated. can you help on that

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wkdc0b7f/7/ , there you go, everything for you just add the `div` and the jQuery. Also explained step by step.

Comment: thank you sir. Working on it. This seems like the RIGHT answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert datepicker on document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#ui-datepicker-div" ).datepicker( "show" );
});
```

Comment: Yes Kiran. It sure is. I just need to have it displayed constantly without the click event. Like it should be displayed all the time.

Comment: can you provide the link where you want to implement it. :)

Comment: it is in the initial post. However it is twomoms.kitchen

Comment: @maddysanoo where on your page is this `<div id="ui-datepicker-div"></div>` ?

Comment: also @maddysanoo in your `head` tag before `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">` you have an closing `</style>` tag, remove.

Comment: Ylama the datepicker is on the checkout page. Add product and you will see on the checkout page a field called pickup date. Also my script tags are before </head>

Comment: Kiran, I did not get any error. By putting what you and Ylama said, the page gets blank. Nothing else.